# How to continue an interrupted simulation?

Tags: netlogo

How can I continue a interrupted simulation in Netlogo ? Is it possible to continue a simulation from a backup ?

Comment: What do you mean by an interrupted simulation? How was it interrupted What do you mean a backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [`export-world`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#export-world) and [`import-world`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#import-world), or the File menu items "Export World" and "Import World" which do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks very much Seth. To continue running the model from the point where it left off, I don't understand where I must put "export-world" in the code to regularly back up simulations. Must I put "export-world" in `ask turtles [ ]` as follows: `ask turtles[ export-world ...... ]` or at the beginning of my code ? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You can call `export-world` any time you like, but a typical place to do it would be at the end of your `go` procedure, after `tick`.

Comment: Thanks very much Seth. If I call `export-world` several time in the code, the output file .csv is rewritten at each time ?

Comment: If the file name is the same, it will be overwritten. Use a different file name each time to keep them all.